# Binding SSL Certificate Reset in Win 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8

On a Windows 2012 server we create websites using C# code.
This also applies the https binding w/ SSL.

For some reason whenever a new site is created it sets **all** sites' SSL cert to "Not Selected"
**Is there way to prevent this?**

[image]

Code we use

```
 //get the server manager instance
            using (ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager())
            {
                SiteCollection sites = mgr.Sites;
                Site site = mgr.Sites[siteName];
                if (site != null)
                {
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv";
                    startInfo.FileName = "appcmd.exe";
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("set site /site.name:\"{0}\" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='{1}:443:{2}']", siteName, ipAddress, hostHeader);

                    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                    {
                        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("Site: " + siteName + " does not exist.");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that appcmd interacts with IIS8 in exactly the same way as with IIS7 (haven't poked around with it yet), the answer is **NO**.

SSL termination is handled in the HTTP stack before the request reaches IIS. For that reason, certificate-to-endpoint assignment is handled by the OS, not by IIS. `appcmd.exe` only updates IIS configuration files, it doesn't interact with OS dependencies like certificate assignment.

When you use `appcmd set site` you are effectively resetting/overwriting the previous site configuration.

To update certificate-to-endpoint mappings you need to use `netsh.exe` as outlined in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591597/how-to-assign-a-ssl-certificate-to-iis7-site-from-command-prompt

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=baf9926b466e8565217b5e6287c97973dcd54874 appid={ab3c58f7-8316-42e3-bc6e-771d4ce4b201}
```

where `baf9926b466e8565217b5e6287c97973dcd54874` is the certificate thumbprint, and `0.0.0.0:443` is the ip endpoint (`0.0.0.0` means the same as "Any Unassigned")

**UPDATE:**
If you always use existing endpoints for HTTPS bindings (eg. always "Any Unassigned":443), I believe you could successfully overcome this issue by backing up the following Registry key (including subkeys):

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo
```

Write it back to the registry after you've run `appcmd set site`